# How to block specific sites on Asus wifi router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dns, blocking

I have [this router](http://www.asus.com/Networking/RTN12_C1/) (`Asus Wireless-N300 Router`). Also I have `Windows 7 workstation` and `ipad 4`. `The workstation` is connected to router with help a `ethernet cable`. `Ipad 4` gets internet on `wifi`.

I want to block specific sites on wifi network. For example, I want to block the site http://example.com on Ipad, but this site have to work on the workstation. To complete this task, I wish to block sites for Wireless network. I don't know, how to do this.

The router has a classic dashboard, which available on http://192.168.1.1/ But there is no some setting, which can block sites on wifi.

I know one workaround solution. I can deploy own dns server, add domain `example.com` to black list in this server, and add `example.com 23.43.41.15` to host file on windows workstation. But this solution is so complicated for such simple task.

Answer (score 1):

probably default firmware is not able to do that, but personally I always choose routers which are able to run 3rd party firmware.

Luckily your router is supported by one of the best 3rd party firmwares: DD-WRT. You can check the support status by entering "N12" into search field here:
http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/support/router-database

And here are detailed upgrade instructions:
http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Asus_RT-N12

Once you are on DD-WRT, just open router IP (default is 192.168.1.1), default login is "root" and password is set on first login.

Then go to "Access Restrictions" and enter desired sites under "Website Blocking by URL Address" or even block by keyword here "Website Blocking by Keyword".

Detailed description from DD-WRT:

> Website Blocking by URL Address:
>       You can block access to certain websites by entering their URL.
>
> Website Blocking by Keyword:
>       You can block access to certain website by the keywords contained in their webpage.

Final recommendation: Do all work over Ethernet cable only, do have downloaded latest original ASUS firmware and recovery procedure to you computer, or make sure you have backup Internet connection available (example direct internet without router).

Comment: thank you for response. I have one question. How to block sites only for WI-FI network? Default asus firmware allows to block sites by url. But, if I add some site to block list, then this site will be blocked for workstation too. But I don't want to block sites for workstation.

Comment: Hello @Denis, unfortunately default possibilities do not allow this. The WiFi and Ethernet LAN are on one VLAN and firewall features are also common for all of them.
There is possible advanced solution: to add allow rules for specific IP addresses, i.e. your workstations, which allows ALL HTTP traffic on them. Please refer http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/url-blocking-via-iptables-655678/

Comment: The RT-N12 can run TomatoUSB (I use the Shibby builds from http://tomato.groov.pl on an N12 in access-point only mode) which will enable per-device access restriction. But be aware, while it opens up a lot of capability, changing to non-factory firmware can be challenging. It's easy to brick the device by accident. Be sure to find and download or print instructions for doing a full factory reset BEFORE working on your router!